# How to get/install xmkmf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to compile FreeNX like so

```
aptitude install build-essential
apt-get install subversion patch
apt-get install expat fontconfig xterm zlib1g libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libpng12-0 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libfreetype6
apt-get install zlib1g-dev libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libpng12-0-dev

svn checkout svn://svn.berlios.de/freenx/trunk
cd /root/trunk/freenx-server
patch -p0 < gentoo-nomachine.diff
make
make install
```

but `make` fails as it can't find `xmkmf` which seams to be a program for creating Makefile's.

Does anyone know how to get/install `xmkmf` on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install `xutils-dev`  package.

To look for information similar to this, use `apt-file find` command, for example

`apt-file find xmkmf`.

Comment: Incredible useful tool. I'll definitely use it from now on. xutil-dev -> xutils-dev